# Construction of the sentences and difference "What" and "How"

Tags: sentence-construction, difference, verbs, adjectives, questions

Which one is correct and why? When does use How or What?  And Does it need to use "Does" or doesn't?

> What does this song called? or How does this song called?
>
> What does this game call? or How does this game call?
>
> What is this game called? or How is this game called?

Comment: I don't know the prior or the latter context, but quite 100% sure the first one is entirely and without any question is against the grammar of English. I want the OP to improve the q personally.

Comment: You need to do some research on: How to ask questions in English.

Answer (score 0):

Only one is correct, and that would be

> What is this game called?

Since **does** is a "helping" verb to an other existing verb in the sentence, there is just no place for it in here. For example,

> What *do* you **call** this game?

There needs to be some sort of "helping" verb in order for you to construct said question. Omitting that, you would not be able to form a grammatically correct question.

Additionally, the basic difference between *what* and *how* is that using *what* you are asking on the goal and using *how* is asking on the journey to said goal. Put it simply,

> What did you achieve?

Would be question on specific final result, contrasting which

> How did you achieve it?

Is asking on the "steps" that led to mentioned result.